# unable to login in proper email and name

Tags: php, html, ajax, mysqli

I'm creating login form using AJAX, i'm basically work on PHP i don have much knowledge on ajax, please if u people could help me with my doubts, when i enter any value in the email id and name then its getting logged in to the page and suppose if i give wrong name and email then instead of throwing the error message like invalid email or name its getting logged in even with wrong email id  and name, i'm purely new to this AJAX please can any one help me out with this issue it would be really help full please

login.php

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                <script src="script.js"></script>
                <style>

                .error {
                    color: red;
                    display: none;
                }

                .div1 {
                    margin-top: -19px;
                    margin-bottom: -25px;
                    margin-left: -19px; 
                }

                .copy {
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    padding: 6px 20px;
                    border-style: ridge;
                }

                #error_message{
                    background: #F3A6A6;
                }

                .ajax_response {
                    padding: 10px 20px;
                    border: 0;
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-top: 20px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    display:none;
                    color:#555;
                }

                </style>
            </head>
            <body style="background-image: url(pic.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">  

                <div style="padding-left: 380px; padding-top:80px" class="div1">

                    <h2 style="color:#009999">Login :</h2>

                    <form action="" method="post" id="logForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <span style="color:#0099ff">Name: </span>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="copy" style="margin-left: 52px"  value ="" />
                        <span class="namee error">Enter name</span>
                        <br/><br/>

                        <span style="color:#0099ff"> E-mail: </span>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="copy" style="margin-left: 48px"  value ="" />
                        <span class="emaile error">Enter email</span>
                        <br/><br/>

                        <input type="button" id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
                        <div id="error_message" class="ajax_response" style="float:left"></div>

                    </form>

                </div>

            </body>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#submit").click(function(){
                        var error = false;
                        var form = document.getElementById('logForm');
                        var formData = new FormData(form);

                        // Loop through the form data
                        for(var p of formData){
                            // Check if the form data is empty
                            if(p[1] === ''){
                                // Show the error
                                $('.'+p[0]+'e').show();
                                error = true;
                            }
                        }

                        // Boolean to prevent AJAX from running in case of an error
                        if(error){
                            return false;
                        }

                        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "success.php",
                            data: formData,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data){

                                if (data) {
                                    window.location = 'pannel.php';
                                    $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
                                    }, 2000 );
                                }

                            }

                        });

                    });

                });
            </script>

        </html>
```

success.php

```
        <?php
                $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
                session_start();

                if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                    header('location:pannel.php');
                        }

                    $email=$_POST["email"];
                    $name=$_POST["name"];

                    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name='$name' and email='$email'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
                    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                    if($rows==1){
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                        $_SESSION['id']=$row1['userid'];
                        // Redirect user to index.php
                        header("Location: pannel.php");
                        }
                         else{
                             $error = " Invalid Name or E-MAIL ";
                            }
            ?>
```

pannel.php

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
                <head>

                    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    <style>

                            #success_message{
                                background: #CCF5CC;
                            }

                        .ajax_response {
                            padding: 10px 20px;
                            border: 0;
                            display: inline-block;
                            margin-top: 20px;
                            cursor: pointer;
                            display:none;
                            color:#555;
                        }
                    </style>

                </head>
            <body>

                <div id="success_message" class="ajax_response" style="float:left"></div>

                <div class="container">
                    <br><br><br><br>
                    <?php

                        $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
                        $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `users` where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
                        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                        echo 'Welcome - '.$row['name'];

                    ?>

                    <br>
                    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                    <br><br>



                </div>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: `PHP's` `header()` doesn't work in ajax mode. WHat you should do is return a success/failed message via `PHP`. Then check for that message using javascript and proceed accordingly.

Comment: did not got u sir please can u edit my code and let me know please m new to ajax i tried all the suggestion which all i got but unable to do so please can u edit my code and let me know

Comment: `if (data) {   window.location = 'pannel.php';` does not make any sense. Instead redirect in the PHP to the page. Nothing AFTER this statement will be executed since the page will immediately change to pannel.php. You should not use AJAX here at all or not redirect in the success

Comment: sir as i said m new to this ajax concept please can uguide me a bit more briefly im not getting what u said sir

Comment: Don't use AJAX if you need to redirect in the succes. If you still want to use AJAX, return the content of the pannel.php and render it. If you do not understand what I mean, please read some tutorials

Comment: i read alot of tutorials sir but im not getting how to fix my issue so i pasted here can u please edit my code and let me know please

Comment: it would be really help full for me sir please

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider:

1.)  You are not using parameterized sql queries thus leaving your db open to sql injection.  I changed your query structure to demonstrate how to use parameterized queries. Please stop doing it the way are doing it.  Here is a link on this subject.  Read it, bookmark it, and refer to it until you understand it. It's that important and not hard once you do it a few times.

https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

2.) When you use ajax here is what it happening.  Your main html page is sending out an ajax query to another page.  That page receives the response, does whatever code, and then sends an answer back to the main html page's ajax function that sent the request.

That response is received in the success block of the ajax function.  The easiest way to pass data back and forth in my opinion is using the JSON format.

3.) Anything echoed in php will be sent to the ajax function.

4.)The data in my example is a json string not a json object so you have to convert the string to a json object.

5.)When building new code, do it in small blocks and do not move on until whatever you are working on works how you would expect.  Then embellish the working code to do what you want.  This will save you hours in troubleshooting and help you figure out the best workflow of your code before you spend hours coding what you think is going to happen.

6.) You can use name and emails for validating a login, but names are common and people can share emails.  I would do something like an email/username and a password.  For passwords use the php's native password functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

So here is an example that should get you on the right track.

On your login.php change your ajax function to this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "success.php",
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(response){
    console.log('Ajax tried.');
    console.log(response);
    var data = JSON.parse(response); //Change from string to object.
    console.log(data);
    if (data['success']) {
        console.log('It worked!!!!');
        //The user's name and email returned a 
        //result from the user's table. 

    } else{
      console.log('You have an error.');
      console.log(data['errors']);
      //Here are your errors.  Do something with them.
    }

  }

});
```

Change your success.php to this:

```
<?php

session_start(); //Always do first.

$mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){ //<--This should not be here.  This should
//be tested for on the login.php page.
$errors['logged_in'] = TRUE;  

}

//Checking is user existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name=? and email=?";  //<--Use placeholders.

//Remember this:  Prepare, bind, Execute.



$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); //Prepare
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['email']); //Bind
$stmt->execute(); //Execute.
$result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

if($result){

  $_SESSION['name'] = $result['name']; //Safer to use data from db instead of post.
  $_SESSION['id']   = $result['userid'];

}else{

  $errors['user_exists'] = FALSE;

  }

$stmt->close(); //Important to free up resources for your next query.

$response = array();

if(isset($errors) && $errors){

  $response['success'] = FALSE;
  $response['errors'] = $errors;

} else{

  $response['success'] = TRUE;


  }

echo json_encode($response); //<-- This is what gets sent back to ajax function.

?>
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I added a few console.log() lines in the ajax function for trouble shooting.  Add them in and run, let me know what your console says.

Comment: are you using your browser console to check for errors? I added another console.log() in the ajax function.  Please add it to your code, run and tell me results.

Comment: Again, are you using your browser console to check for errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172807/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-keerthi-patil).