# Error while login with valid credentials

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have a simple ajax login page, as shown below. I'm trying to get it working for 4 days but don't know why it's not working.
Even if I enter valid email ID and name, it shows invalid credentials, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

*login.php*

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>

    <head>
        <title> login script with ajax</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:#b3ffff">

        <div style="padding-left:500px ; padding-top:200px">

            Name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name"><br><br>
            E-mail: <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail"><br><br>
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" value="Log In">
            <p style="color:black">Havent Registered? <a href="index.php">Register</a>.</p><br><br>
            <div id="display" style="color:red"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#submit").click(function(){
                        var name = $("#name").val();
                        var email = $("#email").val();

                        var datastring = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email;

                        if(name=='' || email==''){
                            $("#display").html("Please Enter All The Fields");
                        }
                        else{
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "success.php",
                                data: datastring,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(result){
                                    $("#display").html(result);
                                    window.location = "welcome.php";
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

*success.php*

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");


    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        header('location:welcome.php');
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        // removes backslashes
        $name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']);

        //escapes special characters in a string
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$name);

        // removes backslashes
        $email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);

        //escapes special characters in a string
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$email);

        //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name='$name' and email='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
        $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($rows==1){
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            $_SESSION['id']=$row1['userid'];
            echo 'Logged in Successfully '
        }
        else{
            echo ' Invalid Name or E-MAIL ';
        }
    }

?>
```

*welcome.php*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header('location:login.php');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <?php
            include_once 'connect.php';
            $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `users` where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            echo 'Welcome - '.$row['username'];
        ?>

        <!--br>
            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        <br><br-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the output/error its showing?

Comment: You have put `alert()` in your success part of Ajax function. Are you getting that alert?

Comment: yes sir i'm getting alert message saying invalid credentials

Comment: even tough i have entred valid mail id and name

Comment: Is there no password field? You could be vulnerable to hackers logging in as random users if they get hold of a user's email address

Comment: sir how to login in to account i need that sir

Comment: You guys need to do what I already suggested when you posted this same question the other day.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771484/unable-to-login-in-proper-email-and-name/50771977?noredirect=1#comment88553218_50771977

Comment: sorry but its not working sir im means what you said i did but its not working sir

Comment: You need to rebuild the code.  Start with a bare bones ajax model and get it working.  Then add your other code to it until it works.

Comment: sir i have updated my rebuild code please once check it

Answer (score 0):

You really need to make this as simple as possible to troubleshoot. Then when you get this working, slowly add more code to it until it all works.  Do it one step at a time.

Change your success.php page to just this:

```
<?php

$myPostArray = array(

  'name'  => $_POST['name'],
  'email' => $_POST['email']

);


echo json_encode($myPostArray);

?>
```

login.php to this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <title> login script with ajax</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color:#b3ffff">

  <div style="padding-left:500px ; padding-top:200px">

    Name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required><br><br>
    E-mail: <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail" required><br><br>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" value="Log In">
    <p style="color:black">Havent Registered? <a href="index.php">Register</a>.</p><br><br>

    <div id="display" style="color:red"></div>

  </div>

  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){

      var name = $("#name").val();
      var email = $("#email").val();

      if(name  != '' && email != ''){

        var datastring = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email;

        $.ajax({

          url: "success.php",
          type: "POST",
          cache: false,
          data: datastring,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data); //This will show what you get back from success.php.
            if (data) {
              //It works, do something.
              alert('Here is your response from the php page:' + response);
              console.log('Here is your response from the php page:' + 'Name: ' + data['name'] + ' ' + 'Email: ' + data['email']);

            } else{
              //It does not work, do something.
              alert('Your ajax failed to get the info from your php page. Keep troubleshooting');
              console.log('Your ajax failed to get the info from your php page. Keep troubleshooting');

              }

          }

        });

      }else{

        alert('You must enter a valid name and email.');

        }

    });

  });

  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

You really need to be using you console to aide you in trouble shooting this problem. You get much more detailed information.  Stop using alert() to troubleshoot.

Comment: @pavan kumar  Change your login.php and success.php to exactly what I have in my answer.  Make sure both files are in the same directory.  Run it and let me know.

Comment: @pavan kumar Make sure the url in the ajax function is "success.php"  I had a different one in there.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have tested that code on my machine and it works.  You should get an alert that shows you the name and email.  Make sure that the login.php and success.php files are both in the root directory and that both those file are identical to what I have posted.

Comment: When you run the code I have posted in my answer what does it do?  Do you get any errors?  Do any alert windows popup? Do you see anything in your console?  You need to tell us more than it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Both your AJAX and PHP codes require some fixing. Also try to use password in login instead of Email and Name only. Try fixing both your AJAX Code and PHP code.

Use the following code in your AJAX.

```
<script>
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    var formData = {
        'name'              : name,
        'email'             : email
    };

    if(name=='' || email==''){
         $("#display").html("Please Enter All The Fields");
    } else {
         $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "success.php",
              data: formData,
              dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
              encode          : true
              success: function(data){
                   console.log(data);
                   if(data == 1) {                       
                       window.location = "welcome.php";
                   } else {
                       $("#display").html("Please Enter All The Fields");
                   }
              }
          });
      }


 </script>
```

in PHP:

instead of $_REQUEST['name'], $_REQUEST['email'] try using $_POST['name'] and $_POST['email']

then `echo '1'` for success or `echo '0'` it it fails.

try building it in block bby block and check for errors as you develop it

Comment: what response do you get?